# I am trying to add TadvTabSet in runtime I have got an error

Tags: delphi, runtime, delphi-xe2, addition

In this code I am trying to add `TadvTabSet` in runtime I have got an error:

> Access violation at address 00DC0FB0 in the module Projet4.exe. read of address 00000258.

The code causing it:

```
with tset.AdvTabs.Add do
begin
  tag:=strtoint(en_vente.Text);
  name:='tab'+inttostr(tset.AdvTabs.count);
  caption:=enom.Text; 
end;
```

I can't see anything that would be a problem. Can someone help figure out why?

Comment: It is much easier to help you if when you say "got an error", the very next thing you do is to tell us what the error is, including the **exact error message**. You have that information right in front of you, and we don't - there is absolutely no reason for you not to provide it. If you want us to help you, **give us the information** we can use to do so.

Comment: The error message is in French language because I yave a Delphi version so, Iam trying to give you a translation  :

Comment: Access violation at the address 00DC0FB0 in the module Projet4.exe. read of address 00000258.

Comment: An address  that low (00000258) usually indicates accessing an object that hasn't been created. First, get rid of the `with`; declare a variable of the proper type, and then use it: `NewTab := tset.AdvTabs.Add; NewTab.Tag := ...` and so forth. Then set a breakpoint at the `NewTab := ` line and step through your code, and figure out which line causes the error.

Comment: what type is TSET, show the declaration and where it is created. Check `tset <> nil` before using it. After that do the same about tset.AdvTabs: show us the declaration of datatype of `tset.AdvTabs` property and check `tset.AdvTabs <> nil` before using it. Also check that `Self <> nil`.

Comment: "The code causing" - that is 4 lines of code having 2 + 2 + 3 + 2 = 9 pointer dereference operations. Each one may lead to AV. Please specify where exactly error does happen. One of options would be to introduce enough temporary variables to make one dereference per line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example that I generally use, except for this answer, the code that creates the components on the TAdvOfficePage was removed.  Don't forget to add any events for the components you add to the TAdvOfficePage.

```
procedure TForm1.AddOfficePage;
begin
  AdvOfficePage := TAdvOfficePage.Create(AdvOfficePager1);
  AdvOfficePage.Parent := AdvOfficePager1;
  AdvOfficePage.AdvOfficePager := AdvOfficePager1;
  AdvOfficePager1.AddAdvPage(AdvOfficePage);
  AdvOfficePager1.ActivePage := AdvOfficePage;
  {Add components next}
end;
```

Whoops... I now see that you wanted to add a TTabCollectionItem to an TAdvTabSet.

```
procedure TForm1.AddTabCollectionItem;
{ Add a TTabCollectionItem to TAdvTabSet. }
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 9 do
  begin
    ATabCollectionItem := AdvTabSet1.AdvTabs.Add;
    ATabCollectionItem.Caption := 'Tab Collection Item ' + IntToStr(i);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

For example with the TPageControl you need to create a tab first and then add to it...
maybe is the same here...

```
myTab:= TTabSheet.Create(YourPageControlAsOwner); 
myTab.name:= ... 
myTab.caption:=... 
//and the asociated events you need after create 
myTab.onClick:= YourOwnMethod...
```

Comment: Thank you I have got the solution, This is the best Site I know.